Simple import missing in multi-module Java with Maven
This might be a super simple and stupid question for all Java developers, but I can't find a way to sort it out myself, and spent too much time in googling. I am fairly new to Java, and I am trying to achieve a very simple functionality - I am creating a simple app that will take a user's input, pass it along and get some output. Using Java version 21, I am keeping the business logic in a module/project called 'cyp' (names of modules are fictional). I want to achieve separation of concerns, so my 'cyp' module handles the business logic, and the main orchestrator is another Springboot module called: 'apiService'. My goal is to get the logic coming from the user interface in the 'cyp' module, and pass it to the 'apiService' module. I have both pom.xml files referencing each other:
Here is the pom.xml in my 'cyp' module:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.cyp</groupId>
    <artifactId>cyp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

**      <-- apiService dependency -->
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cyp</groupId>
            <artifactId>apiService</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>**
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Here is the pom.xml in my 'apiService' module:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cyp</groupId>
    <artifactId>apiService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>apiService</name>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

**      <!-- cyp Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cyp</groupId>
            <artifactId>cyp</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>**

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


I have added the dependencies in both projects and:

did Project->Maven->Reload Project
did mvn clean install

That went smooth.
The modules are located in:
C:\Users\example\.m2\repository\com\cyp\fixApiService
C:\Users\example\.m2\repository\org\cyp\cyp
But, when I am creating a class in the 'cyp' module and I am adding the import: import com.apiService (or import com.cyp.apiService) and run mvn clean install, I keep getting a failure there:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project cyp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/myProjects/cyp/src/main/java/org/cyp:[1,20] package com.cyp does not exist

In my honest opinion, I assume that this should be a simple and straightforward thing to do - but for some reason, it does not work. I have also invalidate cache in the IDE, etc. etc. basically tried everything that I could find online.
I could really appreciate your assistance.
Thanks in advance :)

Looking at your error message, it seems like you are mixing up the package names org.cyp (from your file path) and com.cyp. Anyway, you should try to break up your circular dependency chain by, for example, only having the apiService-module depend on the cyp-module.

org.cyp is the location where my 'cyp' project 'lives' within .m2/repository structure, i.e. .m2\repository\org\cyp\cyp and the apiService module is at .m2\repository\com\cyp\apiService. So you are saying that I should be adding both modules in one solution (project) ? I was trying to achieve separation of concerns and having them both as completely separated modules.  I have removed the dependency from the apiService module that points to the cyp project, and only left the one in the cyp project that points to the apiService, did mvn clean install on both modules, no luck

I think you should change your "cip" module, it should not depend on "apiService" module, you would face a cyclic dependency issue here.
Regarding your error, it seems that you have named it incorrectly
Cyp
<groupId>org.cyph</groupId>
<artifactId>cyp</artifactId>

depends on
<groupId>com.cyp</groupId>
<artifactId>apiService</artifactId>

apiService
<groupId>com.cyp</groupId>
<artifactId>apiService</artifactId>

depends on
<groupId>org.cyp</groupId>
<artifactId>cyp</artifactId>

it is missing a "h" in the dependency "cyp" instead of "cyph"

The missing 'h' was a typo - I have corrected the question. The problem is that I am trying to create a class in the cyp project that will have a method that will call another method from the apiService module that should handle the core logic. That is why I have the dependency from the cyp project to the apiService one. I have removed the dependency from the apiService module that points to the cyp project, ran mvn clean install on both modules, but I still get the same error as described.

@Lynx The problem is your cyclic dependency. Because cyp depends on the apiService-module, the apiService module needs to be built first. But because the apiService-module depends on the cyp-module again, the cyp-module needs to be built first. So there is no way to build your project with a cyclic dependency. You need to structure your code in such a way that the dependency only goes one way.

I have changed the structure and I am reworking the whole thing under one parent project with both projects as child modules. I have initially build and run the whole lot, and it looks like it works (for now) Thanks :)

Thanks to everyone that reached out - the solution was to remove the circular dependency and place the modules under one parent module. I also introduced a new module that will hold the common logic that will be utilized by the child modules.
